# Underscore.js, _.map, replace the original values in array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to know why values in 'arr' have not been changed by _.map function. Why 'newarr' works?

Instructions:
Write a program that uses console.log to print the numbers from 1 to 100.
  For multiples of three, print "Fizz" instead of the number. For multiples
  of five, print "Buzz" instead of the number. For numbers which are multiples
  of both three and five, print "FizzBuzz".

```
var arr = [];
for(i=1; i<101; i++){
  arr.push(i);
}

var newarr=[];
_.map(arr, function(num){
  if(num%5===0 && num%3===0){
    num='FizzBuzz';
  } else if(num%5===0){
    num='Buzz';
  } else if(num%3===0){num='Fizz';
} else {}
  newarr.push(num);
  return num;
});

console.log(newarr);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `_.map()` function **returns** a new array. It does not modify the original array.

If you wrote

```
arr = _.map(arr, function(num){
  if(num%5===0 && num%3===0){
    num='FizzBuzz';
  } else if(num%5===0){
    num='Buzz';
  } else if(num%3===0){num='Fizz';
} else {}
  newarr.push(num);
  return num;
});
```

you'd reassign the variable `arr` and there'd be no need for `newarr`.

If you really want to modify the original list, use `.each()` instead of `.map()`:

```
_.each(arr, function(num, i, arr){
  if(num%5===0 && num%3===0){
    num='FizzBuzz';
  } else if(num%5===0){
    num='Buzz';
  } else 
  if(num%3===0){num='Fizz';
  } else {}
  arr[i] = num;
});
```

That version updates the array explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`map` doesn't change its argument array; it returns the resulting array instead.
If you wish the result to be stored the same array, please tell it explicitly:

`arr = _.map(arr, function(num)`  ...